# Give example of bitset as a member of structure in C++

Tags: c++

I don't know how to use bitset as a member of structure.As I am getting this
**[ERROR]: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'bitset' with no type**

code:

```
typedef struct
{
    bitset<10> status;         //bitwise status 
}Status;
```

Comment: It's `std::bitset`. And don't forget to `#include <bitset>`

Comment: i have already done that. but still it's giving this error

Answer (score 1):

It's often considered courteous on Stack Overflow to give more examples of what you're tried, and where you've looked for help.  For example you might say that you're tried to understand the contents of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

But here goes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>  // you'll need to include this

struct status_t {
    std::bitset<11> status;  // note the std - it's in that namespace
};

int main()
{

 status_t stat;

 for (auto i = 0; i < 11 ; i += 2)
    stat.status.set(i);

  std::cout << "values: " << stat.status << "!\n";
}
```

You can see it run at [cpp.sh - Bitset example](http://cpp.sh/63on)

Answer (score 1):

This sort of error can be caused by either omitting the bitset include, or failing to specify the std namespace.

To rectify the problem:

1) Make sure you're including bitset:

```
#include <bitset>
```

2) Make sure the std namespace is specified:

This can be done either 'globally' within the file using the directive:

```
using namespace std;
```

or by prefixing the bitset declaration with std:

```
std::bitset<10> status;         //bitwise status
```

So, your final file fragment could look something like this:

```
#include <bitset>

// other code ...

typedef struct {
    std::bitset<10> status;      // bitwise status
}Status;

// the rest of the file ...
```

Comment: Rinkal, I'd add this comment to your question instead of my answer if I had 50 reputation, but as I dont...can you provide more details about the problem?  Perhaps a complete source file, the operating system you're running, and the compiler you're using?